# Why do we need Trains?

Tags: transportation

I was wondering that why do we need trains. My arguments are as followed.

1. Trains require tracks and hence we need to lay down steel tracks and sleepers and stones. It costs a lot of money.
2. Tracks themselves are problematic because, even if a small piece is missing, then the entire track becomes futile, hence rendering a railway system useless is very easy.

Why don't we instead just lay down tarmac instead of tracks and hence creating a system in which buses or vehicles with similar functionalities can ply? This system would be much more flexible than existing track system.

The problem with driver fatigue can be solved by creating mostly straight stretches, hence requiring driver input for a limited period of time.

Comment: Welcome to the site Clarkson.  It sounds like you are asking what the benefits of Rail transport are compared to over the road travel...which isn't really world building.  A quick google search of 'benefits of rail versus truck' gives many reading options.

Comment: I don't know if this is a Worldbuilding question, but I can comment that it is because it can rapidly transport a heavy volume more efficiently than other modes over land.

Comment: Apparently you haven't ever noticed that the axle load for a 315,000lb gross weight 4-axle bogie wagon (heaviest 4-axles in routine US interchange service, albeit only on some portions of the network) is on par with the weight of a fully loaded (to Interstate federal limits) tractor-semitrailer.

Comment: Just have a look at the transported goods per driver, and you'll immediately recognize one advantage of railways.

Comment: I disagree that this is not about worldbuilding - This is a highly useful question if you're wanting to know about building a world - If you're creating a sci fi world for example, why include trains?

Comment: @Miller86 *Any* real-world fact could potentially be used in worldbuilding. We have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: Given the [username](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Clarkson), it's pretty obvious that this question is just trolling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1.Trains require tracks and hence we need to lay down steel tracks and sleepers and stones. It costs a lot of money.

This is, however, much less costly than a multilane highway. [Here, for instance](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijp5aEvPLJAhXKeT4KHeZOCpcQFgg-MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Famericandreamcoalition.org%2Fhighways%2FHighwayCosts.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF777oMehFKVXR6cvR_weOyc3VoEw&sig2=bYC7dW2UghddoR0oEMHMGg) it is suggested that average interstate costs are ~100 million per mile for a 2-lane highway. Since separate direction roadways are required for safety, that's about 200 million per mile. [This paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFnZOTvfLJAhUIWz4KHaGbBO0QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flib.dr.iastate.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1392%26context%3Detd&usg=AFQjCNEhh5uXbUY3VKeHNRAdnn416ISouQ&sig2=pEJ12Xva_I6ORbNTbnsK1g), on the other hand, suggests railway costs on the order of 3 to 4 million dollars per mile.

Fuel costs are lower, as well. [Peterbilt's latest](http://www.roadandtrack.com/new-cars/news/a4173/news-peterbilt-cummins-tractor-trailer-fuel-economy/) gives a mileage of about 10 mpg for a total 65,000 pound vehicle. Assuming about 15,000 pounds for the vehicle and trailer, that's about 10 mpg for a 25-ton load, or about 250 ton-miles per gallon, and this is touted as being twice the average efficiency for the industry as a whole, so current numbers are more like 125 ton-miles per gallon. Meanwhile, the rail industry typically claims something like 400+ ton-miles per gallon and [the railway industry](https://www.aar.org/todays-railroads/our-network?t=economicandpubicbenefits) claims 4 times better energy efficiency than trucks.

> 2.Tracks in themselves are problematic because, even if a small piece is missing, then the entire track becomes futile, hence rendering a
>   railway system useless is very easy.

Well, yes. Are you truly suggesting that the US should build its commercial transport network with guerilla warfare in mind? How much would armor plating tractor-trailers cost?

> Why don't we instead just lay down tarmac instead of tracks and hence
>   creating a system in which buses or vehicles with similar
>   functionalities can ply, this system would be much more flexible than
>   existing track system.

Done. It's called the Interstate Highway System. Particularly for relatively short runs the flexibility does give highways the edge, and the effect has been well-known since the 50s. Railways are mostly dominant for long-range shipping or extremely bulky goods. Coal is an example where trucks simply don't compete economically.

> The problem with driver fatigue can be solved by creating mostly
>   straight stretches, hence requiring driver input for a limited period
>   of time.

Sure, if you're going to allow automated trucks. They're just coming into being.

Comment: Also: Trains are safer. You don't have to worry about the engineer getting tired, drifting out of his lane, and hitting a train travelling in the opposite direction. Well, its possible for trains to derail, but it's much less likely than a car drifting out of lane. And, trains require why fewer people for the same amount of cargo than trucks, so labor costs are lower.

Answer (score 1):

Rail, like canals or even improved roads, allows you to transport more materials more quickly and at a lower unit cost.

The initial set up costs are high (so is digging a canal or building a modern or even Roman road), but the advantages are so great that the cost can be amortized over a huge amount of traffic, either in the form of passengers or by tonnage of cargo, that the investment can pay for itself quite quickly.

Railroads also confer military advantages, since you can transport troops, weapons and bulk supplies rapidly to the railheads, and support far more troops than would be possible with traditional horse drawn wagons on unimproved roads. This can be seen by comparing the sizes of the armies of the Napoleonic wars era with the armies of the American Civil War.

In fact, rail traffic is still economical today in terms of transporting bulk supplies over long distances. The modern interpretation is "unit trains" which have all the cars carrying a single type of good. The low friction of rail provides good fuel economy, and the ability to couple multiple cars together allows for carriage of thousands of items or thousands of tons of goods.

Comment: Re the military uses of railroads: it should be kept in mind that one of the requirements underlying the grade limits and vehicle load weight capacity on the US interstate highway system was the need to accommodate tank transporters in the event of a future major war.